# How to write connection string when ms access database is password protected?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, app-config

My Code is

```
  <add name="conn" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Db\abc.mdb"/>
```

My Database Password is `123`
How to write full connection String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example as per [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/):

> `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.mdb;
>       Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;`

Add this to the connection string according to the requirement.
Ref:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Comment: how about username ?